# Is the use of % in printf operator overloading? If not, what is it?

Tags: java, operator-overloading

Please explain what happening here:

```
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 43%2;
    System.out.printf("The test remainder is %d %s",a,"hello");
 }
}
```

In the above code i want to know is it [operator overloading](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) of the `%` operator?

Comment: Are you asking about the `int a = 43 % 2;` or the use of `%` in the format string?

Comment: Java currently doesn't support operator overloading. The only built-in operator overload is for numeric and `String` values.

Comment: while i replacing or removing % from string, output not shown. if changing order of  %d %s then exception thrown. why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Java currently has very limited support for operator overloading, and this is not one of those cases.

The `%` in the [string literal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) is handled by the implementation of `java.util.Formatter`. `String#format` and `PrintWriter#printf` delegate the formatting work to `Formatter`, which manually parses the string.

The only reason % has value there is due to how `Formatter` handles the string.

If you view the code, you'll find:

```
if (conversion == '%' || conversion == 'n')
```

followed by a switch statement which handles the different types.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're confused by the usage of `%` in a `String`.

Anything that is enclosed between `""` in Java is not an operator. So when you have code like
 `43 % 2` the `%` is an operator but when you have a `String` like `"asdf%asdf%++*adsf"` the `%` `+` and `*` are not operators. Also Java doesn't have operator overloading.

The `printf` function uses `%` to mark the position where it will later put the variables you pass to it, it could've been any other symbol and has nothing to do with operator overloading.