# How to make assignable, number-like class in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a number-like class in Java that would allow objects to be created like this:

```
MyClass x = 3;
```

Instead of this:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass(3);
```

And could be used like this:

```
float i = x/2;
```

Instead of this:

```
float i = x.value()/2;
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first example:

> MyClass x = 3;

This will never be possible, since the `3` in this case is a primitive type, which is an `int` and not a real `Object` like `MyClass`. This simply will not work since Java is not designed like that.

For your second example:

> float i = x / 2;

You are looking for [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). Unfortunately this is not supported in Java: [Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java/1686714)

So to answer your question:

**No. You can't do any of this in Java.**

Comment: can I at least `typedef float MyType`?

Comment: seems like I can't do that either. Oh god, java suuuucks. How on earth am I supposed to create an alias for float when it's used for a specific purpose?

Comment: Nope. Java is very limited. You could try to use C# which has support for the elements you want and has a lot of similarities of Java.

Comment: If I could, I would, unfortunately the choice of language wasn't mine. Thanks!