# Scala: method\operator overloading

Tags: scala

The following example is from the book 'Programming in Scala'. Given a class 'Rational' and the following method definition:

```
def add(that: Rational): Rational =
    new Rational(
        this.numer * that.denom + that.numer * this.denom,
        this.denom * that.denom
    )
```

I can successfully overload the add method with a convenience version that takes an Int argument, and **makes use of the definition above**:

```
def add(that: Int): Rational =
    add(new Rational(that, 1))
```

No problems so far.

Now, if I change the method name to an operator style name:

```
def +(that: Rational): Rational =
    new Rational(
        this.numer * that.denom + that.numer * this.denom,
        this.denom * that.denom
    )
```

And overload like so:

```
def +(that: Int): Rational =
    +(new Rational(that, 1))
```

I get the following compile error:

```
(fragment of Rational.scala):19: error: value unary_+ is not a member of this.Rational
+(new Rational(that, 1))
 ^
```

Why is the compiler looking for a unary version of the `+` method?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Scala, any construct of the type `+x`, `-x`, `~x` and `!x` is transformed into a method call `x.unary_+`, etc. This is partially to allow Java-like syntax of having `!b` as the negation of the boolean `b`, or `-x` as the negation of the number `x`.

Therefore, the code snippet `+(new Rational(that, 1))` is translated into `(new Rational(that,1)).unary_+`, and as `Rational` doesn't have this method, you get a compile error. You will get this error only if your function is called `+`, `-`, `~` or `!` as these are the only characters Scala allows as unary operators. For example, if you called your function `@+`, the code compiles just fine.

Though, I would suggest writing the overridden add function as:

```
def +(that: Int): Rational =
  this + (new Rational(that, 1))
```

This code shows the intent of your function better -- you add a new `Rational` constructed from an integer as a numerator and `1` as denominator to `this`. This way of writing gets translated into `this.+(new Rational(that, 1))`, which is what you want -- invoking the `+` function on `this`.

Note that you can use the infix notation however the function is called. For example, if you change the name back to `add`, you can still keep the definition as:

```
def add(that: Int): Rational =
  this add (new Rational(that, 1))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you call `+` with explicit `this`, it should work

```
def +(that: Int): Rational = this.+(new Rational(that, 1))
```

Scala allows to define unary operators that can be used in prefix operator notation. For example you can use `+` as a prefix operator to achieve the same:

```
def unary_+: Rational = this.+(new Rational(that, 1))
val a = new Rational(3,2)
val b = +a
```

Without explicit `this` in your example, the compiler thinks that you are using unary operator `+` which is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified the binary + operator, you've specified the unary + operator.

So instead of:

```
def +(that: Int): Rational =
  +(new Rational(that, 1))
```

You need to write this:

```
def +(that: Int): Rational =
  this +(new Rational(that, 1))
```