# Ruby method for +=

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

Is there a way to make Ruby able to do something like this?

```
class Plane
  @moved = 0
  @x = 0
  def x+=(v) # this is error
    @x += v
    @moved += 1
  end
  def to_s
    "moved #{@moved} times, current x is #{@x}"
  end
end

plane = Plane.new
plane.x += 5
plane.x += 10
puts plane.to_s # moved 2 times, current x is 15
```

Comment: Just rename your method to something else?

Comment: yep, i guess so.. since += cannot be overloaded (i know this just now) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331962/list-of-ruby-operators-that-can-be-overloaded

Comment: It is confusing to use the same variable names `@moved` and `@x` for the class and its instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+=` operator is not associated to any method, it is just syntactic sugar, when you write `a += b` the Ruby interpreter transform it to `a = a + b`, the same is for `a.b += c` that is transformed to `a.b = a.b + c`. Thus you just have to define the methods `x=` and `x` as you need:

```
class Plane 
  def initialize
    @moved = 0
    @x = 0
  end

  attr_reader :x
  def x=(x)
    @x = x
    @moved += 1
  end

  def to_s
    "moved #{@moved} times, current x is #{@x}"
  end       

end

plane = Plane.new
plane.x += 5
plane.x += 10
puts plane.to_s
# => moved 2 times, current x is 15
```

Comment: `a += b` is called an *abbreviated assignment*. When Ruby's parser sees that the first thing she does is convert it to `a = a + b`. Ruby has 13 operators (mostly methods) that can be expressed as abbreviated assignments. All have the form `o=`, where `o` is an operator and `a o= b` expands to `a = a o b`. Those operators are `+`,`-`,`*`, `/`, `%`, `**`, `&&`, `||`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<` and `>>`. (Source: The Ruby Programming Language, 1st ed., by Flanagan and Matsumoto, p 96.)

Answer (score 6):

1. You cannot override compound assignment operators in Ruby. The assignments are handled internally. Instead of `+=`, you should override `+`. `plane.a += b` is the same as `plane.a = plane.a + b` or `plane.a=(plane.a.+(b))`. Thus you should also override `a=` in `Plane`.
2. When you write `plane.x += 5`, the `+` message is send to `plane.x`, not `plane`. So you should override `+` method in the class of `x`, not `Plane`.
3. When you refer to `@variable`, you should pay attention to what the current `self` is. In `class Plane; @variable; end`, `@variable` refers to the **instance variable of the class**. That's different with the one in `class Plane; def initialize; @variable; end; end`, which is **instance variable of the class's instances**. So you can put the initialization part into `initialize` method.
4. Operator overriding should be treated carefully. Sometimes it is productive and expressive, but sometimes it isn't. Here I think it's better to define a method (e.g. `fly`) for plane rather than using some operator.

```rb
class Plane
  def initialize
    @x = 0
    @moved = 0
  end
  def fly(v)
    @x += v
    @moved += 1
  end
  def to_s
    "moved #{@moved} times, current x is #{@x}"
  end
end

plane = Plane.new
plane.fly(5)
plane.fly(10)
puts plane.to_s
```