# Can I implement += in my class to increase a contained value?

Tags: ruby

Consider

```
class Container

  def initialize(value = 0)
    @value = value
  end

  def + (other)
    return @value + other
  end

  def - (other)
    return @value - other
  end

  def * (other)
    return @value * other
  end

  def / (other)
    return @value / other
  end

  def get
    return @value
  end

end
```

I would like to use `+=` to increase the value in the container, like this:

```
c = Container.new(100)
c += 100
print c.get   # Expecting  200
```

The above won't work, as `100` will overwrite `c`.

I know I could use something like an `attr_accessor` to generate a getter and setter for the value, but I'm curious if I could do this in a prettier way such as using `+=`.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `c.value += 100` ? Is there any reason not to use attr_accessor for this?

Comment: @tigeravatar: That's an option, but I just want to know if I could just do c += 100. If not, then sure, I'll use attr_accessor.

Comment: Before thinking about `+=` try `c = c + 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `c += 100` is just a sugar for `c = c + 100`, you can't escape overwriting `c`. BUT you can overwrite it with a similar object (and not with fixnum, as in your question).

```
class Container
  def initialize(value = 0)
    @value = value
  end

  def + (other)
    Container.new(@value + other)
  end

  def get
    @value
  end
end

c = Container.new(100)
c += 100
c.get # => 200
```

Comment: It's an incredibly bad idea to make `+` mutate the object. `+` should return a new object with the increased value. The way you implemented it, writing `d = c + 100` would change `c` as well as `d`.

Comment: right, my bad. Amending

Answer (score 3):

`x += y` is just syntactic sugar for `x = x + y`. So you only have to implement `+` in your class and you get `+=` for free.

Comment: Correct, however in this case the `+` method returns the result of the added value, and not the instance that implements the method.  Which means `c += 100` would change `c` to a totally different type of object, from a `Container` to a number.  I'm guessing this isn't what @Omega wants.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't overload `+=`. See [list of ruby operators that can be overridden/implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331962/list-of-ruby-operators-that-can-be-overloaded) for the full list of overloadable operators.

In Ruby `x += y` always means `x = x + y`. The only way to change the meaning of `+=` for a given `x` is overriding `+` in `x.class`. However, `+` has a different semantics, and the user most probably expects that `+` returns a new object. If you make `+` return the original `x`, that may confuse some of your users. If you make `+` return a different object, then `x` would point to that other object in your example, and as far as I understand your question you don't want that.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to say *why not*.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't know any deeper explanation, maybe the authors know. The Ruby language was designed and implemented this way.

Comment: As others have noted, it is simply that `a += b` is simply `a = a + b`, so `+=` isn't a "real" operator at all. It may not be in the list of *operators that can be overloaded*, but neither is it in the list of *operators*. `=` cannot be overloaded, because then the dark arts would reign, but `+` *can*.