# What does Hash[x] << "string" do?

Tags: ruby, hash

What does `Hash[x] << "string"` do?

What is the symbol `<<` for and how does it work?

Comment: x is really just a string

Answer (score 5):

The real question is, *what* does `Hash[x]` *evaluate* to?

Because it's *that object* (an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html), perhaps?) on which the `<<` operator (really a method) is being invoked. That is, `Hash[x] << "string"` is, excluding the temporary variable, equivalent to `t = Hash[x]; t << "string"`.

Like all [overridable](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm) Ruby operators<sup>1</sup>, `<<` is really *just a method call*. It is commonly seen as [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), but it may be different for the object in question (see above):

> [On an Array object, the << operator] Append—Pushes the given object on to the end of this array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.

Once the actual object is known, then the operator can be trivially looked up in the appropriate documentation.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [list of ruby operators that can be overridden/implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331962/list-of-ruby-operators-that-can-be-overridden-implemented) for a list; "pure" operators like `=` (non-indexed assignment) and `,` *cannot* be overriden and do not work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is a method that is also usually aliased as `append`. In Ruby, you can call operator methods in the same way as any other method: `an_obj.<<(an_arg)` is perfectly valid syntax.

In general, the append method adds the argument to the receiver. If the receiver is an array, it adds the argument to the end of the array; if it's a string, it adds the argument to the end of the string.

The side effects and return value of calling the `<<` method simply depend on the method's implementation in the receiver object's class.