# ruby String class: what is the "%" symbol a method?

Tags: ruby

In the ruby (2.2.0) [String class documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html), the very first INSTANCE method is the following:

```
str % arg → new_str

Format—Uses str as a format specification, and returns the result of applying it to arg. (...)
```

The first example provided is:

```
"%05d" % 123    #=> "00123"
```

and works as stated. 
Ok, but without a '.' the '%' can't be a method, can it?
And if it is not, what is instead (and why is listed under the 'instance methods'?)

Comment: Because it's an instance method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3331974/438992 Ruby has a lot of syntatic sugar. Same way you can override other operators.

Comment: it is a method just like `==`, `+`, or `my_prop=`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's syntax sugar. You can call it with `.` if you want:

```
"%05d" % 123
# => "00123"
```

is equivalent to:

```
"%05d".% 123
# => "00123"
```

A similar example:

```
1 * 2 + 3
# => 5
(1.*(2)).+(3)
# => 5
```

The second form is valid, but we usually choose the first form as it's clearer.