# "+" operator for Java-classes

Tags: java, class, numbers, operator-overloading

I have a class like this:

```
private static class Num {
    private int val;

    public Num(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add to objects of the class by using the "+"-operator?

```
Num a = new Num(18);
Num b = new Num(26);
Num c = a + b;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can't. `+` is overloaded only for numbers, chars and `String`, and you are not allowed to define any additional overloadings.

There is one special case, when you can concatenate any objects' string representation - if there is a `String` object in the first two operands, `toString()` is called on all other objects.

Here's an illustration:

```
int i = 0;
String s = "s";
Object o = new Object();
Foo foo = new Foo();

int r = i + i; // allowed
char c = 'c' + 'c'; // allowed
String s2 = s + s; // allowed
Object o2 = o + o; // NOT allowed
Foo foo = foo + foo; // NOT allowed
String s3 = s + o; // allowed, invokes o.toString() and uses StringBuilder
String s4 = s + o + foo; // allowed
String s5 = o + foo; // NOT allowed - there's no string operand
```

Comment: `String object somewhere` - not somewhere. It must be one of the first two operands, since `a+b+c` parses as `(a+b)+c` and the plus works only if at least one of the two operands is declared as a String. That's why `o+o+s` doesn't compile while the other two permutations do.

Comment: I thought it had to be the first operand. Nice to know it can be either of the first two.

Answer (score 14):

No, because James Gosling said so:

> I left out operator overloading as a fairly personal choice because I had seen too many people abuse it in C++.

Source: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm

Reference: [Why doesn't Java offer operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/java-operator-overload/194889#194889)

Answer (score 6):

No.  Java does not support operator overloading (for user-defined classes).

Answer (score 4):

There is no operators overloading in java.
The only thing which is supported for objects, is string concatenations via "+". If you have a sequences of objects joined via "+" and at least one of them is a String, then the result will be inlined to String creation. Example:

```
Integer a = 5;
Object b = new Object();

String str = "Test" + a + b;
```

will be inlined to

```
String str = new StringBuilder("Test").append(a).append(b).toString();
```

Comment: Good point, the `+` is a special case for strings, just to make life easier. The compiler replaces string concats with string builders

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible, as [Java doesn't support operator overloading](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-java-doesnt-need-operator).