# Generic method for number types

Tags: java

Is there any way to make a generic method work with its type parameter as if it were a number? For example, consider a method that takes any number and returns its value doubled while keeping the input type.

```
static <T> T foo(T number)  {
    return number*2;
}
```

This doesn't compile because `*` isn't defined for `T` and `int`. Changing `T` to `<T extends Number>` doesn't help, casting `(T)2` doesn't compile either.

Comment: Short answer is no.  You end up doing hairy case statements to check for the various possible types.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thats a shame, I was sure there must be an elegant way to solve this.:(

Answer (score 2):

Generics only work on objects. You can use the `Integer`, `Double` and such classes, but you can't use generics with primatives.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that. But it's still possible to multiply an Integer by 2 and assign the result to Integer variable, right?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on [How to add two java.lang.Numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2721390/199048)

You could convert the values into a known number type and convert it back after the calculation, but this could cause (repeatable) rounding errors.

```
static <T> T foo(T anyNumber)  {
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(anyNumber.doubleValue()).multiply(new BigDecimal(2));
    if (result instanceof Byte) {
        return (Byte) c.byteValueExtract();
    } else if (result instanceof Double) {
        return (Double) c.doubleValue();
    } else if (result instanceof Float) {
        return (Float) c.floatValue();
    } else if (result instanceof Integer) {
        return (Integer) c.intValue();
    } else if (result instanceof Long) {
        return (Long) c.longValue();
    } else if (result instanceof Short) {
        return (Short) c.shortValueExtract();
    } else if (result instanceof BigDecimal) {
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are a and b on the second line? Also, the problem remains - I cant return Byte when the return type is T.

Comment: @user1859055: Sorry, I messed up the variables. It's fixed now.

Comment: `BigDecimal` arithmetic doesn't always give the same result as arithmetic with `Double` and `Float`.  So this will give different answers for certain operations.  Of course, multiplication by 2 isn't such an operation; but I think OP wanted something that will work in general.  Also, division can prove problematic with `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Yes, I mentioned the rounding error, what other problems could occur?

Comment: Basically, whenever you do a `BigDecimal` division, you need to specify how you want the rounding to work - how many decimal places, and which direction.  If you don't do that, you'll get an `ArithmeticException` almost all of the time.  So if OP's method involves division, there needs to be some special treatment that goes beyond what you've done here.  Also, by calling `doubleValue()` on the first line of your method, you can lose a lot of precision if your arguments are `long`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do operator overloading, eg:

```
T number = new T();
number * 5;
```

in Java. I don't know why, but you just can't. Instead, try doing;

```
static <T> T foo(T number)  {
    return new T(number.getInt()*2);
}
```

or something to that effect. Hope it helps.
["+" operator for Java-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883886/operator-for-java-classes)

EDIT:
To expand on what was mentioned in the comments about using Integer i = 5;, this is a feature of Java called autoboxing/unboxing. When you do:

```
Integer i = 5;
i = i * 4;
int n = i;
```

Java is really doing:

```
Integer i = new Integer(5);
i = new Integer(i.intValue() * 4);
int n = i.intValue();
```

Comment: You can't instantiate a generic type.

Comment: Fair enough, I noticed I also assumed number was an int. I'll save this page and fix it in a sec, but right now consider this example broken.

Comment: You probably misunderstood me. T is not my custom class.