# Java conversion toInteger?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I wonder if there is a way to make an own conversion to integer in java. I mean a solution that is comparable to the implementation of the string conversion (toString). I want my class to be interpreted as integer in equation without calling a special function.

```
class MyClass(){
   private int number;

   MyClass(int n){
      this.number = n; 
   }

   public int toInteger(){
       return number
   }
}
```

usage:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass(2);
int result = 1+a;
```

result would be 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), and it's not possible in Java. The closest thing would be subclassing [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), but `+` doesn't work with it. For `String`s `+` works because it has been built in as a special case in the language. There's no way to extend `+`  to work with anything else.

Of course, with your class, `int result = 1 + a.toInteger();` works. Just a little extra work.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't allow operator overdloading/overriding. You cannot do this.

Comment: java doesn't allow **custom** operator overloading. There is a built in overloading..

Answer (score 0):

Java is not C++ you can't overload operators like '+' in Java

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in java. If you are curious enough, check this post 
[Why doesn't Java offer operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/java-operator-overload) which excplains why it cannot be done and compares between java and c++ approaches