# BigInteger +- operations?

Tags: java, biginteger

Is it possible to do +- operations like this somehow?

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("2");
BigInteger result;

a+=b;
//result = a.add(b);
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/java-operator-overload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  Operator overloading is not supported in the Java language.  The syntax only works for the other numeric primitive wrappers via auto-boxing, which wouldn't make sense for `BigInteger` as there's no equivalent primitive.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, no. There is no operator overloading in Java, and `BigInteger` is not one of the special types for which there is compiler magic to support operators such as `+` and `+=`.

Comment: Again immutability is not a reason for not having language support for the arithmetic operators.  `String` is also immutable and there is language support for the `+=` operator.  E.g.: `String foo = "foo"; foo += "bar";`  You're changing the reference `foo`, not the contents of the object it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  `BigInteger`s are immutable, so you can't change the value of `a` after creating it.  And the usual mathematical operators don't work on them either, so you can't do `a += b` either.

You'd need to do what you have commented-out there -- `result = a.add(b);`

Comment: Immutability is irrelevant to the question.  Primitives are immutable too, but you can use the arithmetic operations with them.

Answer (score 0):

No, not on Java. But you could have a look at other JVM languages like Groovy or Kotlin: both are interoperable with Java's `BigIntegers` and `BigDecimal` types and both allow using `+` and `-` operations as you desire.