# How do I Implement Operators in a Java Class

Tags: java, operators

I am attempting to create a unsigned integer class.

```
public class UnsignedInteger extends Number implements Comparable<UnsignedInteger> 
    { 
    ... 
    }
```

Is there a way to implement operators such as; +, -, *, /, <<, >>, |, ^, >>>, <<

Comment: Java does not support overloading operators! `C#` does~ ;)

Comment: I guess i was missing the forest while looking at the trees.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Java does not support Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77718/1679863). The only option you have is define methods like `add()`, `subtract()`, `multiply()`, etc, and write the logic there, and invoke them for particular operation.

You can have a look at [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class to get an idea of how you can define methods to support various operations. And if interested, you can even go through the source code, that you can find in the *src* folder of your *jdk* home directory.

Comment: This is a good answer, I think that some explanation on _why_ operator overloading was discluded from the language would add a lot to it :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum. I have added a link to another post on SO, which describes that.

Answer (score 9):

There are already 5 answers saying that you cannot overload operators, but I want to point out that you can not use arithmetical operators on **objects** at all. They only work with primitive types (`int`, `double`, etc).

The only reason the following code compiles

```
Integer a = 1, b = 2;
Integer c = a + b;
```

is because the Java compiler compiles it as

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(1), b = Integer.valueOf(2);
Integer c = Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + b.intValue());
```

If you want this to work for your `UnsignedInteger`, you have to extend the *javac* (it is possible, though).

Comment: I give a like for the funny ending. That is a good programmer´s joke. Oh java does have String operations

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot override operators in Java.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to override operators in Java. What you can do is define methods to represent the operations, like [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) in the standard library do.

Answer (score 3):

There is a javac-plugin (an annotation processor like Lombok) called "[Java-OO](https://amelentev.github.io/java-oo/)", which adds operator overloading to Java.

It allows you to add operator overloading to your own classes very easily. In addition to this, many of the built-in classes of the Java API also supports operator overloading when using this plugin.
*(For example: Instead of list.get(6) or map.get("hello") you can do list[6] and map["hello"])*

All you need to do is to include the .jar on the classpath when compiling with javac.

There are plugins for all major IDEs: Eclipse, Netbeans and IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Java does not support operator overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesnt support operator overloading, they consider it a bad practice, knowing that they overloaded `+` and `+=` operators for the `String` class

Comment: That's only half true. It's syntactic sugar for strings and converted into `StringBuilder#append()` calls by the javac.