# Invalid Argument Types for Vector

Tags: java

I have a Class called Vector2 that by default creates the vector (0.0, 0.0) with name equal to the empty string. After Assigning the getter and setter methods I am asked to calculate the sum of two vectors. I've tried the following...

```
public Vector2 add(Vector2 other) {
    Vector2 a = new Vector2();
    return other + a;
}
```

When I do this I get an invalid argument type as the addition is invalid for String types. I tried parsing and casting and it will not work. I am new to Java and just can't make the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, arithmetical operators cannot be used on objects and they cannot be overridden (see this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834553/how-do-i-implement-operators-in-a-java-class)).

But let's take this another way: How is Java supposed to know what the `+` should actually do with the class? You need to implement the arithmetic yourself, meaning that you have to break down the add method to the actual algorithm of adding one vector to another.

Since I believe you have a 2D vector only that would be:

```
Vector2 res = new Vector2();
res.a = this.a + other.a;
res.b = this.b + other.b;
return res;
```

Assuming that `a` and `b` are either `int`, `double`, `float` or another primitive, where the `+` operator can be used on.