# How to compare two JSR-363 Quantity objects?

Tags: java, jsr363

I'm trying to use JSR-363 Quantity to manage some quantities in my application. I have some code similar to the following that I would like to convert to use the Quantity class.

```
Double volume1 = 14d;
Double volume2 = 18d;

Assert.isTrue(volume1 < volume2);
```

Using Quantity, I'm trying to find a way to compare two volumes, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the API that's equivalent to the simple comparison above!

```
Quantity<Volume> volume1 = Quantities.getQuantity(14d, Units.LITRE);
Quantity<Volume> volume2 = Quantities.getQuantity(18d, Units.LITRE);

Assert.isTrue(volume1 < volume2); <--- operator < doesn't exist
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14834553/1707353) might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` only works with primitive number types (and boxed equivalents).  You cannot use it with objects.

Use `volume1.substract(volume2).getValue().doubleValue() < 0` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something like `volume1.compare(volume2)` in the API, but this has to do for now I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there's a newer specification for units of measurements and a reference implementation that provides [ComparableQuantity](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/master/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/ComparableQuantity.java) class that implements `java.lang.Comparable`.

The newer standard is [JSR-385](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=385) and its reference implementation is [Indriya](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya).

With this one can do:

```
ComparableQuantity<Volume> volume1 = Quantities.getQuantity(14d, Units.LITRE);
ComparableQuantity<Volume> volume2 = Quantities.getQuantity(18d, Units.LITRE);

Assert.isTrue(volume1.isGreaterThan(volume2));
Assert.isTrue(volume2.isLessThan(volume1));
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I’m glad to know the Units API has been revived!  But it appears ComparableQuantity is implementation specific and is not a part of the API.