# Does Java8 supports operator overloading

Tags: java, java-8

So I'm interested is there a way to overload operator in Java 8? Is there exist something like

```
void operator(){ }
```

in `C++`?

Comment: No, it still doesn't. And I don't believe it ever will.

Comment: No. User-defined operator overloads are not allowed in Java.

Comment: No . Any sources for your question?

Comment: We don't want that in Java. EVER.

Comment: No but actually _Why should Java?_

Comment: @TAsk because C++ can ;)

Comment: Java's designers are extremely committed to backwards compatibility, so `==` will probably never be overridable. If you allowed other operators to be overridable, that would probably cause even more confusion than there is today (see, e.g., the "why can't I compare strings using `==` question that pops up on SO every so often.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no operator overloading in Java 8. If you don't know it yet, you could have a look at [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#operators) which is a JVM language that compiles to pure Java. It supports operator overloading and a lot more features while it's still has a static type system.

(And, of course, there is Groovy, Scala, and other JVM scripting languages which support operator overloading as well).