# Java integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Okay so I am trying to replicate my own sorting algorithm into java as Arrays are my weakest link, and as they say, practise makes perfect. I have all the logic I need for it, but I am struggling with the coding as I am still relatively new to Java (any good tutorials will be appreciated).

1) So the first thing I am trying to do is create a user inputted array of any length that has integers. 
I am basing my code around a string list function I made a while ago except the code does not transfer from String to integer.

The line that the IDE does not like most is when I try and convert:

```
List<String> numList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To

```
List<int> numList = new ArrayList<int>();
```

This is probably a syntax error that I am just unable to solve

2) I would like to write something that in my mind would work as:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numList.size; i++) {
    int number1 = numList[i];
    int number2 = numList[i + 1];
    int sortedArray[];

    if (number1 >= number2) {
        sortedArray[i] = number2;
        numList[i + 1] = number1;
    } else {
        sortedArray[i] = number1;
        numList[i + 1] = number2;
    }
}
```

As you can see the logic and what seems like to me the code, is there however it still does not work and with my limited java knowledge I can not work out why.

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code using the "code" button so it's more readable.

Comment: Are you trying to parse an integer from a string? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I would say you need to use integer arrays (int[]) instead of ArrayList for your exercise

Comment: http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/ nice book for learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) When it comes down to generics, you need to use **classes** and not **primitive** types. As a result Java introduced *schizophrenic* classes for every primitive type. The primitive type of `int` is `Integer`, so you have to use:

```
List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

2) Your second question boils down to *operator overloading*, a concept not (yet) supported by Java. There is however a project described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23782596/67579) that helps you to define operators and compiles it to corresponding Java files.

You need to use [`List<T>#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) and [`List<T>#set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) to manipulate `ArrayList` and `List` objects in general. Furthermore a `List<T>` has no `.length` but a [`List<T>#size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29) method to inspect the size.

Translating your algorithm to a `List<Integer>` for `numList` would thus look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numList.size(); i++) {
    int number1 = numList.get(i);
    int number2 = numList.get(i + 1);
    int sortedArray[];

    if (number1 >= number2) {
        sortedArray[i] = number2;
        numList.set(i + 1,number1);
    } else {
        sortedArray[i] = number1;
        numList.set(i + 1,number2);
    }
}
```

But it will still fail, as you fail to initialize your `sortedArray` (regardless of being an array or `List<T>`). Furthermore it goes out of bounds because of the `<=` in the `for` loop (fix with `<` instead of `<=`).

3) Your concepts looks a bit like *bubble sort*:
[image: bubble sort]

You don't need a `sortedArray`: you simply need to *swap* items. Try to think how you can swap items. That being said, it is probably a bit more efficient to use an array, and furthermore there are faster algorithms like *MergeSort*, *QuickSort* and *HeapSort*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such kind of implementation. This can also work when you are creating Arrays of objects too:

```
Int op[] = new Int[int n];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(op, new Int());
    for(int i=0;i < n; i++){
        op[i].get();
        op[i].processFile();
    }
```