# Trouble comparing values in different Deedle dataframes

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

I have two identical files with different names that are used to populate two different Deedle dataframes. Yet when I try to compare identical values in the two dataframes the program sees them as not equal to eachother.

```
var Df1 = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/File1.csv");
var Df2 = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/File2.csv");

if (Df1["Header1", 3] == Df2["Header1",3])
{
  Console.WriteLine("The computer sees them as equal");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("The computer sees them as not equal");
}
```

If I cast both values, then the computer sees them as equal. Is there anyway to determine if the two values are equal without casting them?

```
var Df1 = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/File1.csv");
var Df2 = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/File2.csv");

if ((string)Df1["Header1", 3] == (string)Df2["Header1",3])
{
  Console.WriteLine("The computer sees them as equal");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("The computer sees them as not equal");
}
```

Comment: What are the values that you're comparing (before you cast them to strings)? Are they numbers? Textual values?

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, that `Df2["Header1",3]` returns an `object`.

If you look at the following link
[== operator MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx), you'll see that default implementation of  `==` for `reference types` returns `true` only if it's the same object (same address on the heap). 

Since `Df1["Header1",3]` and `Df2["Header1",3]` are two different objects `==` operator returns `false`. When you cast the result to `string`, values comparison is used (see same link above) and `==` operator returns `true`.

According to [Deedle ReadCsv](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameExtensions.fs) documentation, only primitive types are inferred, so, if that column contains dates, the return type would be object causing behavior described above

Comment: That seems logical - and somewhat indicative of the risk of overloading "==" in C# vs, say, java, where you have to use a specific method like .equals() if you want to compare the meaning vs. the raw object references.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Interesting point about the risks of operator overloading.
I found a related question on SO that discusses this matter in depth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading. I really liked the second answer (the one with highest score, not the accepted one). Especially the citation of James Gosling and Bjarne Stroustrup. I agree with Stroustrup. The ability to misuse a feature is not a good enough reason to disable it.

Comment: I made use of Df1.Equals(Df2) once @DanielS pointed me in the correct direction