# Define += for custom classes in Java

Tags: java, operator-overloading

I am making a simple 2D physics engine as my first attempt at making any kind of physics engine.  Unfortunately for anybody who's a fan of teaching physics, this is not a physics related question.  I simply wanted to know if there was a way to define something simple like addition for a custom class.  For example, I have created a class named Vector2D.  If I have a velocity vector, and an acceleration vector, it would be easiest to simply have the following code:

```
Vector2D velocity = new Vector2D(xAxisVelocity, yAxisVelocity);
Vector2D acceleration = new Vector2D(xAxisAcceleration, yAxisAcceleration);
void update() {
    velocity += acceleration;
}
```

However, since velocity and acceleration are not primitive types, so I cannot just add them together.  From what I know right now, I would have to add their components together like so:

`velocity.x += acceleration.x`

..and so on..

What I would like to know is: Is there a way to define addition for classes, similar to how `toString()` can be overridden?

Just to clear it up, it isn't that big of a deal for me to make a method for adding the two vectors together, I just want to know if overriding is possible.

Comment: SO won't allow me to post my long answer since this question was marked as a duplicate. So please visit http://pastebin.com/AiHh7cBa to read my answer.

Comment: @EmilyM You can always go post your answer on the linked duplicate.

Comment: @EmilyM Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I've already done.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no operator overloading in Java. It's a design choice and that's what we have to live with.

See [Why doesn't Java offer operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading) for more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

No — there's no user-defined operator overloading in Java. (This is intentional; the language designers felt that this feature of C++ caused too many problems.)