# Advice for novices for how to avoid bugs with operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I got a question from a student of mine asking why the following code results with what he thought to be a mysterious output.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char op = '+';
    int num = 9;
    std::string res =
        "a const char* concatenated with a char and std::string " 
                    + op + std::to_string(num);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

Well, he expected to get: `a const char* concatenated with a char and std::string + 9` and couldn't understand why he gets just `std::string 9`. It's clear that if it was a function call and not an operator the problem would pop right away.

**Any advice I can give novices for how to avoid such bugs with operator overloading?**

Comment: Sorry to be trite but, most people (me included) should avoid operator overloading at all unless it is very very clear what is going on. You have got the canonical example as to why to follow this advice right here.

Comment: @JimmyNJ there's no user-defined operator overloading here, and in fact the problem is related to a non-overloaded operator (`+` with builtin operands)

Comment: But did you explain to the student why he got the results he did? `+` is left-associative, so it's going to attempt C-string literal + char which ends up meaning advance the c-string array point by `int('+')`.

Comment: @greatwolf almost. I asked him: are you sure the opeartor that you think you are calling is in fact the operator being called? He answered - **:-0** but not because he saw the problem, because the question was not clear... eventually he got to it.

Answer (score 2):

`"a const char* concatenated with a char and std::string "` is a `const char[]` literal, not a `std::string`.  Adding an integer (`char` is a small integer) to a C-style array generates a temporary pointer pointing into that array at the numbered offset.

General advice to avoid this sort of problem: Avoid using C-style arrays (including C-style string literals).

You can use a C++ string literal:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;   // need once in the code

std::string res =
    "a const char* concatenated with a char and std::string "s
                + op + std::to_string(num);
```

note the `s` on the end of the literal.  You will need `#include <string>`  -- the original program should have had that too.

---

If you are using an old compiler that does not support `std::string` literals then building a string can also be performed by streaming into a memory buffer:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << "bla bla bla" << op << num;
std::string res = buffer.str();
```