# Difference between object and String object?

Tags: java, string, operator-overloading

Lets take this example:

```
class Class
{
    String object;
    Class ob;

    void display()
    {
        object= object+1;
        ob = ob+1;
        System.out.println(object +" "+ ob );
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Class obj = new Class();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

This gives a *compile time error* :
 **bad operand types for binary operator +
first type find ; second type : int**.
This error points at this line of my code *ob = ob+1;* .

However, when I *eliminate* this line, the program executes in a proper manner (printing the String as null1).

Now my question is, that object and ob are both **objects of class** String and class Class respectively so why/how am I able to add 1 to null value of object and not that of ob?

Comment: Because `+` is defined for strings and boxed primitive classes; but not for any other classes.

Comment: Additionally, please take the time to format your code more readably, and ideally follow Java naming conventions, to avoid distracting potential answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this works is because the java compiler has specific knowledge of the `String` class and knows how to do special things with it, one of which is addition.

When you add something to a string object, the java compiler will replace your addition with code that converts the operand to string (by invoking `toString()`) and then issue a call to `String.concat()`.  And if you add many strings together in one statement, it will create a `StringBuilder` and invoke `append()` to it multiple times, then take the `toString()` of the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support operator overloading. You can only use operators such as `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `<<`, `>>`, `|`, `^`, `>>>`, `<<`, etc. on primitive types and on `String` objects. You cannot implement those operators on instances of your own class.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading) to understand why java does not allow overriding this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have this class

```
class Foo {
    provate int x;
    private int y;
}
```

if you do **Foo myFoo +=1**, what do you accept as a logically correct result operation? `myFoo.x+=1;` ?? , `myFoo.y+=1;` ?? or maybe `myFoo.x+=1 and myFoo.y+=1;` ??

Java doesnt support overloading of unary operators so something like

```
class Foo {}  

Foo +=1;
```

is not valid and not compiling (until now) no matter if Foo has field that do support that operation, String class is one exception that allows you to do that

Answer (score 0):

The full answer is that for class variables Java initializes them with special values for primitives + String, and with null for every other object.
 As for local variables (e.g. defined inside a method ) Java doesn't do anything with them. The error you are getting is caused by the lack of + operator for any other types than primitives or Strings.

If you move the definition `String object;` inside the method your code won't work at all, both `object` and `ob` will be unasigned.