# Defining symbols to java class

Tags: java, math

I've made a Vector class in java and i would like to be able to add 2 Vectors like this and get an answer: 
vector1 + vector2 
how can i define in code that whenever a Vector type is added to another Vector type it will perform a certin calculation and return it?

Comment: Java does *not* support *operator overloading*. https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/268580/why-does-java-not-support-user-define-operator-overloading/

Comment: You cannot do `v1 + v2` like that. You'll have to create an `add` method in the class and do it like `v1.add(v2)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem didn't know _operator overloading_ is a thing. Does any other language support it?

Comment: @rafid059: yes, C++, Python, C#, Haskell, ... But in my opinion (except for Haskell since it is a functional programming language), most of these operator overloading features tend to produce horrible programs, since it is harder to understand what function will actually perform the operator call. Yes, there can be good reasons to do it, but very frequently, it introduces an additional layer of complexity which makes it more error prone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks !

Comment: I think Kotlin does it well.  Try that as an alternative to Java.