# Java - Check for Overflow by default

Tags: java, integer-overflow

Of cause, checked overflow might slow down the code, and therefore not be an option in time critical sections.

In vast parts of the code however, the slight slowdown in execution speed seems irrelevant, and some other languages take care of avoiding overflow by themselves. While I am aware that since Java 8 there are methods in the Math library that allow for checked arithmetic operations, they are quite verbose and a hassle to use.

E.g.:

`a + b`
vs. 
`addExact(a,b)`

Instead I am looking for a way (library/IDE?) that allows me to use `+` as checked addition and so on, and instead provide methods for unchecked arithmetic for the rare case one truly intends the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `+` for checked arithmetic would imply overloading the default operator behaviour, which Java doesn't allow (see [Why doesn't java allow operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading)). Therefore such functionality cannot be implemented.

That said your best bet for saving some typing would be to bind a text snippet to a `+` (so `a +` and `space` turn into `addExact(a,`).

Comment: It certainly is possible to build a parser that automatically replaces every occurrence of arithmetic on a subclass of `Number` with its `exact...` method in the library. The only missing link would now be to find an API that allows me to create me an e.g. .javpre file which only after its run through my parser gets converted to a .java file. The main thing I don't get is, yes, it's a bit of work, but in a language this old why hasn't anybody done it yet?

Answer (score 0):

> Instead I am looking for a way (library/IDE?) that allows me to use + as checked addition and so on, and instead provide methods for unchecked arithmetic for the rare case one truly intends the behavior.

There is no Java IDE / library / Java language feature / whatever that does that.

The Java language doesn't check for underflow.  The integral types use modular arithmetic.  And you won't find any less verbose to do non-overflowing  arithmetic than those methods in the `Math` class.

If you need to do lots of arithmetic with underflow or overflow checking AND you want the language to do something about it, take a look at what some other programming languages do; e.g. the Wikipedia article on [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Methods_to_mitigate_integer_overflow_problems).

Comment: That is kinda like buying a new car because your old one doesn't have a cup holder.